# Does anyone know where i can find source code of turtlesim package?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, turtlesim, source, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to understand how this simple simulator works. I can't find any good explanation. For example, in ros_tuturials they say:

1. run roscore
2. rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
3. rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key

But how it's connected? how it works? (I know there topics,master, etc.).
and what about measure of speed? speed unit = ? (metres per second) . Is there a motor(simulation of it) or it's just moving on the screen from one point to another point?

A lot of questions...

Any ideas, guys?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344199/does-anyone-know-where-i-can-find-source-code-of-turtlesim-package?/) by [ARS](https://answers.ros.org/users/51475/ars/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As with just about every released package, the wiki would be a good first stop to try to find information. In this case: [wiki/turtlesim](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim).

Under the *Package Summary* heading, we find the link to the `Source` repository: [ros/ros_tutorials](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials).

In there, we navigate to the [turtlesim](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/tree/ee5144f314e669cc6c85ea6e93b7da55d090a684/turtlesim) directory, which contains all sources for the package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-15**:
And see #q320046 for a related Q&A which goes into a bit more detail (but discusses the general case).

**Comment by [ARS](https://answers.ros.org/users/51475/ars/) on 2020-02-18**:
thank you)